# How to make index name as any variable Name of our model same class

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using sprinf data jpa elastic search, in which i need whenever i fetch data by like findById(), or something everytime the Name of the elasticSearch index can be diffrent...

```
@Document(indexName = "sampleIndexName" ,createIndex = false)
public class Details_model {

    
    @Id
    private String _id ;
    @Transient
    private String applicationName ;
    private String mime_type;
    private String status;
    private String pageName;
    private String domain;
    private String url;
    private String size;
    private String webLoadTimeInSeconds;
    private String start_time;
    private String time_stamp;
    private String req_headersize;
    private String req_bodysize;
    private String resp_headersize;
    private String resp_bodysize;
    private String timingsend;
    private String timingblocked;
    private String timingdns;
    private String timingssl;
    private String timingwait;
    private String timingreceive;
    private String timingconnect;
    private String identity;
    
    ...
    
}
```

In above code I need my "applicationName" variable to go like index name every time i hit new findBy_id(), or findByMime_type() etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring data Elasticsearch change indexName dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53389760/spring-data-elasticsearch-change-indexname-dynamically)

Comment: findById searches by id, findByMimetype by a mmetype. Where should the value of applicationName come from in the searches?

Comment: Actually at the  time of let's say Calling findByApplicationName() i also want to send index name every time.

Comment: @SagarPatel  no i have read it but it dosent. please read my last comment.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.